# Android 6.0.1 unable to resolve IP using DNS.

Tags: android, dns

I've have an android 6.0.1 navigation system. The idea is to connect 4G/3G USB modem to have an internet on it constantly.
Found an article how to setup auto installation and configuration of USB modem.
basic idea is to call

```
pppd call conf-pppd
```

where conf-pppd

```
ttyUSB1
460800
defaultroute
noauth
noipdefault
user ""
password ""
connect "/system/bin/chat -f /etc/ppp/peers/conf-chat"
```

where conf-chat
is set of AT commands

```
TIMEOUT 3
ABORT 'BUSY'
ABORT 'ERROR'
ABORT '+CME ERROR:'
TIMEOUT 3
'' 'AT'
OK 'ATZ'
OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","fp.com.attz"'
OK 'ATDT*99#'
CONNECT ''
```

After all problems it almost works, I mean modem connects to 4G network and I even can ping any IP from terminal.
But chrome says some DNS error though I've set

```
setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
setprop net.dns2 8.8.4.4
setprop net.ppp0.dns1 8.8.8.8
setprop net.ppp0.dns2 8.8.4.4
```

here is some android state info which I was able to gather:

DNS info

[image: dns state]

IP route info

[image: ip route show]

ifconfig

[image]

Wasn't able to google anything useful, would appreciate any help, what to check or maybe where to post this question if it isn't appropriate forum.
Thanks.

Comment: can you try with `setprop dhcp.ppp0.dns1` and `setprop dhcp.ppp0.dns2`

Comment: will try today, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ifconfig usb0 192.168.225.3 netmask 255.255.255.0

ndc network create 9792

ndc network interface add 9792 usb0

ndc network route add 9792 usb0 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.225.1

ndc resolver setnetdns 9792 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

ndc network default set 9792

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////